# Want to get start and end date as selected by user from calendar from ngxdaterangepicker in angular. Also the dates in between

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, ngx-daterangepicker-material

I want to read the data between the range as selected by user, but I am not able to get start and end date as selected. Although in console I am able to see it in moment, But don't know how can we get those dates and perform queries.
Also get the dates in between selected range. For ex: below : should return betweendates = [7/11/19 , 8/11/19]

[image: Here console log]

```
<input type="text" matInput
    ngxDaterangepickerMd
    [locale]="{applyLabel: 'ok', format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'}"
    startKey="startDate"
    endKey="endDate"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedDaterange"
    name="daterange"
    (change)= 'selectDateRange()'
    placeholder="choose date"/>
```

```
selectDateRange() {
    console.log(moment().format());
    console.log(this.selectedDaterange);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to get the javascript `Date` object

```
this.selectedDaterange.startDate.toDate();
this.selectedDaterange.endDate.toDate();
```

Check the following documentation for all the examples on how you can use moment

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/

Comment: It's giving error "this.selectedDaterange.toDate is not a function" If run like this -- moment().toDate() , it's returning today's date, not the date I am selecting.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the start and end date. Can you please try again?

Comment: Glad to hear it. Make sure to upvote/accept the answer if it was useful to you :)

Comment: Hey, i want to get dates between selected dates. Can you help me out please.

Comment: Sure, why don't you start a new question and explain exactly what you mean?